# Angular Show Container Based on Property in Object Array

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I currently have a `div` in my Angular component template that should only be toggled if at least one objects properties in an object array is set to true. For example:

```
var object = {
   property: true || false
};
```

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="checkArrayContents()">
    // show stuff
</ng-container>
```

Because of the Angular digest cycle, this is being fired many times and is actually making my app freeze because it's checking every element of an array every single time.

If I change one of the elements' `property` property to true by a click event for example, how can I notify the template to show my container.

I can clarify or add more information as needed.

Comment: Your checkArrayOfContents method is probably faulty. Post the code. But to answer your question: just recompute if the div should be shown or not every time you click, and store the result in a flag in your component. Also, what's wrong with the type `boolean`? Isn't it simpler than `true || false`?

Comment: @JBNizet I was just showing that the property could be either or. Thanks for the answer. It was correct.

Comment: Angular does not have a digest cycle like AngularJS. It uses zones for change detection.